# Refillable lists in batch

Tags: list, batch-file

So. Currently I am working on a game where you create your own nation in Batch. There are bills passed by congress that you can either sign or veto. Once you do so, the bill disappears. After some time a new bill will pop up. The thing is there is a bill limit of 5, meaning that there can only be 5 bills waiting your approval at a time.

Here is the code so far.

```
:leg
title Borderlines BETA - Legislation
cls
echo =====
echo 1-Legislation (%notify_leg%) ===== 2-Disputes (%notify_disputes%) ===== 3-Mailbox (%notify_mailbox%)
echo =====
echo Legislation
if %notify_leg% GTR 0 (
    echo You have new bills from Congress awating your approval!
) else (
    echo Its been a slow day in %nation%...
)
echo ---
echo Select a bill...
echo %leg_01%
echo %leg_02%
echo %leg_03%
echo %leg_04%
echo %leg_05%
echo.
echo ---
echo A - Home
echo.
echo ---
set /p leg_choice=""
if %leg_choice%==A goto home
if %leg_choice%==1 goto leg
if %leg_choice%==2 goto disputes
if %leg_choice%==3 goto mail
if %leg_choice% GTR 3 goto bill_%leg_choice%
goto home
```

Basically %leg_01%, %leg_02%, and so on are the slots. When you create your nation, the bills are assigned. When you pass or veto a bill it removes the notification.

However lets say over time another bill gets added to the list. How can I have it so that once you sign or veto the bill it will remove it from the list, tell the program that a slot is available, and move up the remaining items all the way to the top. This would be essential because there could be, eventually, multiple bills in the game that will show up on that list.

Hope that makes sense ~

Comment: What is supposed to happen when a 6th appears? Does it overwrite the oldest? Does it still exist but isn't shown?

Comment: @Regejok So far there are only 5 because I could not figure out how to replace the slots.

Comment: @Regejok well I can replace the slots it is just that when deleting the new bill from the slot, the program will not know which one to delete from the list...

Comment: Do you mean deleting the most recent one? If it's always the first one, you can use the function I provided below and shift upwards to reassign them.

Comment: @Regejok Deleting the one the user chose. For example, since 1, 2, and 3 keys are occupied by the toolbar. So the bill numbers would be 4, 5, and so on. But these numbers are within the legislation slot varibles so that when new bills are ready, they would have a different number. This is to avoid confusion and to make the program work.

Comment: @Regejok tl;dr The user's choice

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I wrote a function that might me of help in deleting a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suit your needs?

```
:newleg
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
for /l %%# in (4 -1 1) do (
    set /a n=%%#+1
    call set leg_0%%n%%=%%leg_0%%#%%
)
set leg_01=%~1
```

Call with `call :newleg This_is_a_new_leg`. All values will be shifted downwards, i.e. leg_05 is lost, the value of leg_04 is assigned to leg_05. leg_01 will be redefined as the specified parameter.

If you'd like to avoid quoting values with spaces while calling the function, you can use `%*` instead.

You can also keep the values of leg_06 and so on by increasing the limit in the for-loop (n-1, in this case "4").

You can delete an item from the list and then shift upwards with this function:

```
:delleg
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
set leg_0%1=
for /l %%# in (1 1 5) do if not defined leg_0%%# call :dl %%#
exit /b
:dl
set /a n=%1+1
for /l %%# in (%n% 1 6) do (
    set /a n=%%#-1
    call set leg_0%%n%%=%%leg_0%%#%%
)
exit /b
```

Call with `call :delleg 2` to delete leg_02.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just some quick questions. 1. Why is there `exit /b`? Is that important? 2. What does `call set leg_0%%n%%=%%leg_0%%#%%` do? Otherwise thanks! (I didn't even know that you could call sections... That would be quite helpful in the future!)

Comment: @RecyclingBin Just thought the function wouldn't be of much use without any parameter given. It would delete the first item of the list and shift downwards anyway. When %1 is empty, it exits.

Comment: Well currently I have it so that some text like `No new bill is available in this section`

Comment: @RecyclingBin That's when you echo them. The idea is that when for some reason you would call it without a parameter (`call :newleg`), _02 becomes _01 and _01 becomes empty.

Comment: Okay so that basically replaces the variable and the result is the echo. Gotcha